# use your trained language model in recognize_sphinx() using python with pocketsphinx

Tags: python, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I've trained my langue model with cmu sphinx and now I want to use it in speech recognition using python script. How to change the default language model or how to use the trained model in recognize_sphinx().

Answer (score 1):

c = r.recognize_sphinx(audio, language='zh-cn')